# postgreSQL join gives error

Tags: sql, postgresql, cpanel

This join is

```
SELECT 
s.id,
s.sector_abbr,
s.sector_desc,
l.id,
l.sector_id,
l.vendor_address_id
FROM sectors s
LEFT JOIN sector_vendor_address_link l
ON s.id = l.sector_id
```

is giving me this error

`ERROR: ERROR: permission denied for relation sector_vendor_address_link`

Using this id and password through razorSQL, I was able to do updates to these same tables, so I can't imagine it is a permissions problem. Perhaps I am wrong. Is my join just malformed?

Thanks!

EDIT:

It seems that I must manually set All privileges for each table. Is there any way using phpPgAdmin to globally set a users permission for the entire database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set privs for newly created tables using [`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html).

For existing tables you must use [`GRANT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-grant.html) to assign the desired rights. The `ALL TABLES` clause will be useful for that job.

Comment: Thank you. Will that work for tables that I create in the future as well?

Comment: @thomas The documentation explains that. `GRANT` affects only *existing* tables; that's why `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` exists, so you can change the privileges of *future* tables not yet created.